# Why does this undefined variable causes the remaining code to stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

When I initialize const one's value to any number or string, my code runs well and shows the expected alert. But in the code below or in any other scenario which I leave an undefined element between other codes (like "const one;" or "const one"), the alert function stops working. If this is the case with javascript, how can I draft some undefined values to fill out later on in my js files?

```js
const button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];

const one = ;

button.addEventListener("click", showAlert);

function showAlert() {
  alert("lol");
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
```

Comment: If you want `one` to be permanently undefined use `const one = undefined;`. If you want `one` to be temporarily undefined until you assign a value to it later on use `let one;`.

Comment: I just tried putting that forgotten semicolon beside the '=' sign but that doesn't help. Even this version still causes the alert to stop working.

Comment: If immutability after assignment is important, then use `const one = { value: undefined };`, then assign with `Object.freeze(Object.assign(one, { value: 1 }));`.

Comment: @lejlun this solved the issue in both cases, thanks!

Comment: @canistrophedon Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @SebastianSimon this is also a good way to debug, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword is used for declaring variables which have an immutable binding to their values, so that you can't redetermine what they reference. For that reason, trying to declare a variable that way and assigning no value to it causes a `SyntaxError` to be thrown, since that variable wouldn't even be useful, considering you couldn't change its value afterwards.

If you want to declare a variable with an undefined value and change that value later, you should use `let`. Remember the correct syntax to create the variable would be just `let one` (`let one = ;` would be invalid).

```js
const button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];

let one;

button.addEventListener("click", showAlert);

function showAlert() {
  alert("lol");
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```